# Where is XPathEvaluator in android web browser?

Tags: javascript, android, xpath, webkit

We can use the XPathEvaluator object(in javascript) to do xpath evaluation on Safari,Google Chrome and Safari on Iphone. But on android the browser said that the XPathEvaluator object is undefined.

So how can I get a instance of XPathEvaluator object, or is there any other solution to perform xpath evaluation on android browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, there is currently [no XPath in Android](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=515). If you really need XPath you'll have to use a JavaScript implementation ([eg](http://coderepos.org/share/wiki/JavaScript-XPath)). This'll be slow, so prefer DOM traversal if you can.

Comment: that link is for Java XPath support...  Not WebCore

Comment: in fact, the 3.0+ webview supports XPath, as does the java.javax library for same (haven't played with the <= 2.3 in the same fashion, so I cannot comment on that